# Using XmlReader.ReadToDescendant()

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I'm trying to read through an XML (Actually a GML, but I don't think that makes a difference) and have been running into issues with parsing.  This is my first brush with dealing in XML.

My code in C#

```
void ParseXML(String path)
{
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( new FileStream( path, FileMode.Open ) );

    reader.Read();

    while( reader.Read() )
    {
        // Only detect start elements.
        if ( reader.IsStartElement() && reader.Name == "gml:featureMember" )
        {
            Debug.Log(reader.Name);
            reader.ReadToDescendant("gml:featureMember");
            Debug.Log(reader["ogr:X"]);
        }
    }
}
```

A section from the GML I'm working with:

```
  <gml:featureMember>
    <ogr:fence_neighbors fid="F1">
      <ogr:Name>Xyz Xyz</ogr:Name>
      <ogr:X>2353.45361911000</ogr:X>
      <ogr:Y>-4652.36641288000</ogr:Y>
    </ogr:fence_neighbors>
  </gml:featureMember>
```

Making this slightly more difficult is that I am working without access to System.Xml.Linq (Unity3D).  I get reader.Name just fine, but reader["ogr:X"] always comes up null.  It seems like I'm not using ReadToDescendant and Reader properly, but I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: So, when you say "I get reader.Name just fine", exactly what do you get? Come on now, do not hide information from us, we are here to help.

Comment: You also want to put `reader` into a `using` block, so it is cleaned up when you're done.

Comment: Please pardon my inexperience, but what do you mean when referring to a `using` block?

Comment: @karl using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( new FileStream( path, FileMode.Open )) {   // the rest of your code }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XmlReader` does not know about the namespace prefixes as you're using them.

Here is a test program that does what I think you're after.  Note that the namespace URI is given explicitly.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;


class SOTest {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ParseXML(args[0]);
    }

    static void ParseXML(String path)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( new FileStream( path, FileMode.Open ) );

        reader.Read();

        while( reader.Read() )
        {
            // Only detect start elements.
            if ( reader.IsStartElement() && reader.LocalName == "featureMember" && reader.NamespaceURI == "gml-namespace-uri" )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
                reader.ReadToDescendant("X", "ogr-namespace-uri");
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInnerXml());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added declarations to the source document for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wrapper xmlns:gml="gml-namespace-uri" xmlns:ogr="ogr-namespace-uri">
  <gml:featureMember>
    <ogr:fence_neighbors fid="F1">
      <ogr:Name>Xyz Xyz</ogr:Name>
      <ogr:X>2353.45361911000</ogr:X>
      <ogr:Y>-4652.36641288000</ogr:Y>
    </ogr:fence_neighbors>
  </gml:featureMember>
</wrapper>
```

The output is simply

```
gml:featureMember
2353.45361911000
```

Answer (score 1):

The `gml` and `ogr` strings represent namespaces. The element you are looking for is `featureMember`. So you need to call

```
reader.ReadToDescendant("featureMember");
```